# Laravel - Using allfiles gives back empty array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I've been using laravel for nearly all my projects and I've came across a problem when trying to list all files in a directory.

Here is my code below:

```
            $directory = ("upload/"."$username->username");

        $scanned_directory = storage::allfiles($directory);
```

So as you can see First line is the directory which is in Upload followed by the username of the account.

The second line is meant to scan this directory and list only files. Sadly it always gives me back an empty array. Using Scandir() here works... But it gives me folders which I'm not wanting.

So... Any tips? I checked the API and I really can't see what is wrong here :(

Answer (score 5):

The reason you're getting no results when using the `Storage::allFiles('directory')` method is this method only looks inside of your application's storage folder, usually `storage/app`. Hence why modifying the storage path in configuration works as mentioned by @yassine (you shouldn't do this).

If you wish to use files outside of the `storage` folder, simply use the `File` facade instead. e.g. `File::allFiles('directory')`

Answer (score 1):

Me too i had the same issue for local storage. I fixed it by :

1. project/config/filesystems.php
2. line 44
3. changed root folder to from storage_path('app') to changed to
   base_path()

then I provided a related path to the root folder in Storage::files() or Storage::allfiles().

Like Storage::allfiles("app") if I want to fetch files withing the sub folder "app" relative to the base path given in the config file.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

`$direcotry` has to be an absolute path from your laravel root folder.

When your uploaded folder is in the root folder try this

```
$directory = base_path("upload/"."$username->username");
$scanned_directory = storage::allfiles($directory);
```

Comment: But surely that would lead to the laravel install and not the public folder as seen here: "C:\xampp\htdocs\darkkv\darkkv\upload/xenzibe"

Comment: When the upload folder is in the public folder use `piblic_path()`

Comment: Yup done that. Same issue. Trust me everything to do with directories I have tried.

Comment: What will he print for `echo $directory?` Maybe the `$username->username` is a problem. Try it with a hard coded path So you know if it's the directory path or the function.

Comment: Tried that, Same problem. I even tried just scanning public_path() and it still returned null.